# Check if document with keyword already exists in Flutter with FIrebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i'm trying to check if a user with a specific username already exists in my database.
I already tried it:

```
String checkUsername(String username) {
    if (username == null) {
      return "Enter a name";
    } else {
      Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot = FirebaseFirestore
          .instance
          .collection('User')
          .where("searchname", isEqualTo: username.toLowerCase())
          .snapshots();
      print(snapshot);
      if (StaticObject.isNull(snapshot)) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return "Username is already used";
      }
    }
  }
```

but that didn't worked

so maybe someone can show how to check it correctly

Comment: "that didn't worked" Why not? What did you do with this code? What did you expect it to do, and what did it do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore
  .instance
  .collection('User')
  .where("searchname", isEqualTo: username.toLowerCase())
  .get();
print(snapshot);
if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
  return null;
} else {
  return "Username is already used";
}
```